# How do I install wmutils on Fedora easily?

Tags: fedora, dependencies

I've tried to compile

```
https://github.com/wmutils/core
https://github.com/wmutils/libwm
```

But I get

```
CC util.c
util.c:4:10: fatal error: xcb/xcb.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <xcb/xcb.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I also use Homebrew but didn't see a tap for it.

How do I compile this? I tried getting the missing dev package but it wasn't available.

I try to stay within software that's simple to install so I wonder - is there an easier way I'm not seeing?

Comment: Can you try: `sudo dnf install libxcb-devel xcb-util-keysyms-devel xcb-util-devel xcb-util-wm-devel xcb-util-cursor-devel` ?

Comment: You can ask dnf to install the package providing a file by e.g. `dnf installl /usr/include/xcb/xcb.h` in this case

Comment: @taliezin worked like a charm, mind writing it an answer?

Comment: @hakunin feel free to add things you did as answer, I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sudo dnf install libxcb-devel xcb-util-keysyms-devel xcb-util-devel xcb-util-wm-devel xcb-util-cursor-devel
```